# How do I increase the performance of my alpha beta pruning minimax algorithm with memory and iterative deepening

Tags: python, minimax

I have created a game in python like tic-tac-toe where I can choose the size of the board and amount of pieces you need in a row to win. I also have created a bot with minimax, alpha-beta pruning, transposition tables, and iterative deepening. I'm using python and my board representation is just a 2d array. For some reason my algorithm is only calculating like 600 nodes per second when there are chess engines out there with 100,000+ nodes per second. I know python is slow and the board representation would affect the speed, but I don't think it should be only calculating around 600 nodes per second. I also have an evaluation function that does a loop of the whole board and evaluates the position of the pieces. I'm just trying to figure out how to speed up the algorithm because it seems unreasonably slow.

My algorithm:

```
def tt_minimax(board, plr, alpha, beta, depth):
    global tt_start_time
    if ITERATIVEDEEPENING and timeit.default_timer()-tt_start_time >= MAXTIME:
        return "UNFINISHED", 0

    alpha_org = alpha

    tt_code = tt_hash(board)
    pv_move = []
    if tt_code in TRANSPOSITION_TABLE:
        tt_entry = TRANSPOSITION_TABLE[tt_code]
        if tt_entry[3] >= depth:
            if tt_entry[2] == 0:  # checking for Exact
                return tt_entry[0], tt_entry[1]
            elif tt_entry[2] == -1:  # lower bound
                alpha = max(alpha, tt_entry[1])
            elif tt_entry[2] == 1:  # upper bound
                beta = min(beta, tt_entry[1])

            if alpha >= beta:
                return tt_entry[0], tt_entry[1]
        else:
            pv_move = tt_entry[0]

    global tt_node_count
    tt_node_count += 1

    moves = find_moves(board)
    #random.shuffle(moves)

    if pv_move:
        moves.insert(0, moves.pop(moves.index(pv_move)))

    # if drawn
    if len(moves) == 0:
        return "none", 0

    # maximizing
    if plr == 1:

        best_score = MIN
        best_move = []
        for movePair in moves:
            y, x = movePair[0], movePair[1]
            board[y][x] = plr

            wt_code = tt_hash(board)
            if wt_code in WIN_TABLE:
                test_result = WIN_TABLE[wt_code]
            else:
                test_result = test_for_win(board)
                WIN_TABLE[wt_code] = test_result

            if test_result == plr:
                evaluation = 1000 + TTD + depth
                if evaluation > best_score:
                    best_score = evaluation
                    best_move = movePair
            elif depth > 0:
                returned = tt_minimax(board, 2, alpha, beta, depth - 1)
                if returned[0] == "UNFINISHED":
                    return returned
                return_eval = returned[1]
                if return_eval > best_score:
                    best_score = return_eval
                    best_move = movePair
            else:
                evaluation = evaluate(board, 2)
                if evaluation > best_score:
                    best_score = evaluation
                    best_move = movePair

            board[y][x] = 0
            alpha = max(alpha, best_score)

            if beta <= alpha:
                break

        tt_store(TRANSPOSITION_TABLE, board, alpha_org, beta,
                 best_move, best_score, depth)

        return best_move, best_score

    # minimizing
    else:
        best_score = MAX
        best_move = []
        for movePair in moves:
            y, x = movePair[0], movePair[1]
            board[y][x] = plr

            wt_code = tt_hash(board)
            if wt_code in WIN_TABLE:
                test_result = WIN_TABLE[wt_code]
            else:
                test_result = test_for_win(board)
                WIN_TABLE[wt_code] = test_result

            if test_result == plr:
                evaluation = -1000 - depth
                if evaluation < best_score:
                    best_score = evaluation
                    best_move = movePair
            elif depth > 0:
                returned = tt_minimax(board, 1, alpha, beta, depth - 1)
                if returned[0] == "UNFINISHED":
                    return returned
                return_eval = returned[1]
                if return_eval < best_score:
                    best_score = return_eval
                    best_move = movePair
            else:
                evaluation = evaluate(board, 2)
                if evaluation < best_score:
                    best_score = evaluation
                    best_move = movePair

            board[y][x] = 0
            beta = min(beta, best_score)

            if beta <= alpha:
                break

        tt_store(TRANSPOSITION_TABLE, board, alpha_org, beta,
                 best_move, best_score, depth)

        return best_move, best_score
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is more than somewhat faster than Python. C is a LOT faster than Python. Converting this to C would be HUGE. Then you can ask again because the way something is coded in C is also HUGE. Multiply many tens faster by many tens faster and your program will be screaming in C.

Python, well, suffice it to say that Python is not meant to be fast. Speed was not a factor in Python's initial design and now that everything is an object... Suffice it to say that Python gets slower as it gets better. I like Python for its purpose, but C has a purpose too. Your program is a perfect example of the purpose of C. Use Python as a wrapper to play the game. Use C to calculate the next move.